# Randomly generating a word with an existing word

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, random

**What I have to do**

Create a program that asks a user for a word of any length.  Then randomly generate a new word of the same length using only the letters of the first word.  Use any letter any number of times. Ensure you capitalize only the first letter of the new word.  NOTE.  If there is a space in the user word, then you’ll have a space in your output.  Capitalize each word.  Example:

User Word : Dogma
Randomly generated word might be Gogoa  or  Oogma or Gmado  notice, only in the last example did I actually use each letter exactly once.
You must: Use an array, a loop, conditional, function (other than onclick), your code must start with Onclick.  Use all BP’s.
Algorithm:

determine the length of the word.

- slice the word into an array of letters…. use a loop
- randomly generate a number between 1 and the length of the word
- assemble the new word, capitalize the first letter, ensure others are lowercase.
- repeat 3 and 4
- display new word.

(me)

So I have a text box and i used word length to get the amount of letters in that word. Then I have a repeating for loop to get the array from the word 
and I made a random number. How would I turn this stiff into letters and scramble it? I know it isn't nearly done I just want some tips.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Final</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Final</h1>

        Random Word generator <br>


        <input type="text" id="word">
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Randomize" onclick="Random()">

        <script language="javascript">
            word = document.getElementById("word").value
            var n = word.length;
            function Random(){
                for(start = 0; start < n; start++){
                    Array.from(word)
                    do{
                        var x = Math.round((Math.random() * n) + 1);
                        function capitalize(str) {
                            return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
                                return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    while{
                     x != n;
                    }
                document.getElementById("word").value = (capitalize(word));
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at here for the shuffle function : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42334240/5483521

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your string, you can use `split` on the string to get an array.

From here you can shuffle the array with something like: [Shuffle array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)
Now you want to grab the first element and uppercase it. Then you can use `Array.join('')` to get your new string. `Array.join` takes a value for seperator, which in your case you want to be '' so you don't end up with a string looking like `H,e,l,l,o`.

Comment: so how am i doing so far? Mozilla said i have a few errors with it i hope you could help. http://pastebin.com/Vi5dgr22